# Two uniform distribution with same PDF. Find $P(X<Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables such that

$$X\sim U(0,2); Y\sim(1,3)$$

Then $P(X<Y)$ equals?

Answer (score 2):

If $X<1$ or $Y>2$ then certainly $X<Y$. This happens with probability $3/4$. Otherwise both $X$ and $Y$ are in the range $[1,2]$. Conditional on this happening they are both uniformly distributed within this range, so each is equally likely to be larger. Thus overall the probability is $\frac 34\times 1+\frac 14\times\frac 12=\frac 78$.

Comment: How is the probability of X<1 or Y>2 = 3/4?

Comment: $P(X<1)=P(Y>2)=1/2$, and these events are independent.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is the product of the marginal distributions. Hence,
$\mathbb{P}(X<Y)=\int\int_{\{X<Y\}} f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy=\int_1^2\int_0^y\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}dxdy+\int_{2}^{3}\int_{0}^2\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}dxdy=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{7}{8}$.